# mysql load data infile with 2 comparisons

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables each with a column called email_addr. Before a new record is inserted into the database, I need it to check for duplicates in each of these two tables first.

```
         CREATE TRIGGER del_chk AFTER DELETE ON list_no_email
         FOR EACH ROW
         BEGIN
                INSERT INTO list_email(list_name, fname, lname, email_addr)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
         END;//
         delimiter ;
         LOAD DATA INFILE $_FILES[''userfile']
         REPLACE INTO TABLE list_no_email
         FIELDS
                TERMINATED BY ','
         LINES
                TERMINATED BY '\n' (email_addr,id);




+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| date_in    | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| email_addr | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> desc list_email;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| list_name  | varchar(55)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fname      | char(50)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lname      | char(50)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email_addr | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Your trigger is after delete. What does that have to do with checking tables before inserting?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff yes sir. How do I look for dups in 2 columns using load data infile. I really think I am on a bad path here.

Comment: @Barmar I was trying to create a trigger to look for dups because it seemed to make the most sense when comparing with 2 different tables.